# Foreman start not working right on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreman, webpacker, theforeman

I'm trying to run foreman start on my app.

but it gives me an error saying

```
12:53:39 web.1     | started with pid 7647
12:53:39 rails.1   | started with pid 7648
12:53:39 webpack.1 | started with pid 7649
12:53:39 web.1     |  [passenger_native_support.bundle] trying to compile for the current user (hiro_yamada) and Ruby interpreter...
12:53:39 web.1     |      (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
12:53:40 webpack.1 | /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/webpacker-78b2dd910603/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:47:in `exec': No such file or directory - /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server (Errno::ENOENT)
12:53:40 webpack.1 |    from /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/webpacker-78b2dd910603/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:47:in `block in execute_cmd'
12:53:40 webpack.1 |    from /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/webpacker-78b2dd910603/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:46:in `chdir'
12:53:40 webpack.1 |    from /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/webpacker-78b2dd910603/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:46:in `execute_cmd'
12:53:40 webpack.1 |    from /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/webpacker-78b2dd910603/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:11:in `run'
12:53:40 webpack.1 |    from /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/webpacker-78b2dd910603/lib/webpacker/runner.rb:6:in `run'
12:53:40 webpack.1 |    from /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/webpacker-78b2dd910603/exe/webpack-dev-server:8:in `<top (required)>'
12:53:40 webpack.1 |    from bin/webpack-dev-server:17:in `load'
12:53:40 webpack.1 |    from bin/webpack-dev-server:17:in `<main>'
12:53:40 webpack.1 | exited with code 1
12:53:40 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
12:53:40 web.1     | bundler: failed to load command: passenger (/Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/passenger)
12:53:40 web.1     | SignalException: SIGTERM
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:310:in `system'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:310:in `sh_nonfatal'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:337:in `block (3 levels) in compile'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:335:in `chdir'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:335:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpio.rb:70:in `mktmpdir'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:334:in `block in compile'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:378:in `block (2 levels) in try_directories'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:377:in `chdir'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:377:in `block in try_directories'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:371:in `each'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:371:in `each_with_index'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:371:in `try_directories'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:329:in `compile'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:219:in `compile_and_load'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:52:in `start'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:439:in `<top (required)>'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger.rb:240:in `require'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger.rb:240:in `require_passenger_lib'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils/file_system_watcher.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger.rb:240:in `require'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger.rb:240:in `require_passenger_lib'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/standalone/app_finder.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger.rb:240:in `require'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger.rb:240:in `require_passenger_lib'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command.rb:288:in `find_apps'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command.rb:59:in `run'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:51:in `run!'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.1.8/bin/passenger:45:in `<top (required)>'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/passenger:23:in `load'
12:53:40 web.1     |   /Users/hiro_yamada/Dropbox/foriio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/passenger:23:in `<top (required)>'
12:53:40 rails.1   | terminated by SIGTERM
12:53:40 web.1     | exited with code 1
```

How could I fix this issue...?
Thank you for you time.

---

So I tried adding passenger on gemfile and bundling... Still not working.
and I noticed one thing, when I changed my ruby version to 2.2.0 sinc passenger was under a directory ruby/2.2.0/. Then error was returned saying foreman only can run on 2.2.3. Maybe passenger gem I installed is not compatible with ruby 2.2.3??

My procfile and gemfile is

```
web: bundle exec passenger start -p $PORT --max-pool-size 6
rails: PORT=3000 rails s
webpack: bin/webpack-dev-server

source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.2.3"

gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'passenger'
gem 'paperclip', '4.3.6'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'
gem 'ruby-oembed'
gem 'impressionist'
gem 'meta-tags'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'poltergeist'
gem 'webpacker', github: 'rails/webpacker'

# Client
gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'aasm'
gem 'siteinfo_parser'
gem 'open_uri_redirections'

# Exception Notification to Slack
gem 'exception_notification', :github => 'smartinez87/exception_notification'
gem 'slack-notifier'

# login
gem 'devise'

# Oauth
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-instagram'

# Auth
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'

# SNS API
gem 'koala'
gem 'twitter'
gem 'instagram'

# manage constant file
gem 'config'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Pagination
gem 'kaminari'

# Auto-link
gem 'rails_autolink'

#font-awesome
gem 'font-awesome-sass'

# follow, like, mention
gem 'socialization'

# Copy to clipboard
gem 'zeroclipboard-rails'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'foreman'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-doc'
  gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
end

group :development do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Comment: Can you attach your Profile?

Comment: @MaximPontyushenko bash_profile???

Comment: Procfile and Gemfile please

Comment: @phoet info added! Please take a look!

Comment: could you try to run passenger directly without foreman and check if there is an error in any file in the logs directory?

Comment: passenger itself runs fine....

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with Passenger. Try to run only it in development mode and after that in production. You should see error on log output.

It is a most common approach for debugging foreman.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `gem 'passenger'` to your Gemfile and run `bundle`. The issue might be that you installed passenger via `gem install passenger` and bundler doesn't load it.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your advise but still not working.. added my assumption above, please let me know what you think! Thanks!